# Regex replace consider only letters

Tags: asp.net

I want to replace special charter, number, space etc from my string.

For example if i have "123adfei_f g#" it should give me "adfeifg".

```
  string firstvla = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(fname, @"^[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

I am trying to pass the patter which only allow letters (a-z) and A-Z.its not giving me expected result.

is there any best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your string is wrong. What you have means starts with no letters.

Try `"[^a-zA-Z]*"` instead.

Comment: No problem. Since this is the answer, consider marking the 'check' under it so other people know it's the answer as well.